# Invient Chart add on - Vaadin

Tags: javascript, vaadin, highcharts

I am now using Invient Chart add on for my Vaadin project and I am very curious how invient chart invokes the highcharts javascript libs.

-K

Answer (score 0):

The Server side component InvientCharts communicates with the VInvientCharts GWT widget on the client side. This is standard Vaadin server <-> client communication. On the client side the VInvientCharts widget is actually a wrapper for a pure GwtInvientCharts GWT widget. The GwtInvientCharts invokes GwtInvientChartsUtil for making most of the actual calls to the Highcharts JS-library functions. This is done through regular [JSNI](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI.html).

The way the sample includes the Highcharts JS-lib to the generated web page in the example is by using an extended servlet which injects the JS files to the header.

All this can of course be examined more closely by yourself by viewing the code which is included in the add-on package. E.g. drag-and-drop the add-on JAR to Eclipse and then just 
browse Java Resources -> Web App Libraries -> invientcharts-0.x.x.jar.

Hope this was at least part of the information that you were looking for.